# sumifs based on first character in string

Tags: excel

I have an Excel Sheet that needs to be summed if it matches a set of criteria.

If it has the same category, and if the section has a specific first character.

Here is what I have - that should theoretically work - but Excel throws an Error that it is not a function.

`SUMIFS('In Service Costs'!Q:Q,'In Service Costs'!$A:$A,'Labour GL Summary'!$A$2,LEFT('In Service Costs'!L:L,1),"A")`

Comment: I have also tried adding `"=A"` as the last parameter, I also tried `CONCAT("A")` thinking that it was clashing with string syntax

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `LEFT` inside `SUMIFS`, but you can use wildcards in criteria:

```
SUMIFS('In Service Costs'!Q:Q,'In Service Costs'!$A:$A,'Labour GL Summary'!$A$2,'In Service Costs'!L:L,"A*")
```